# change user agent string in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to change my default user agent string in IE 11.  I've heard there are add ons and extensions that do this, but I couldn't find any after an exhaustive search.  I also heard the about:flags experimental feature could do this, but that feature is missing in my ie11.  The f12 feature doesn't work for me because it requires manual users activation which won't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to edit the following registry key.

[image: user agent string]

or if you want a regedit save the below as a .reg file.  Note the reg file doesn't get rid of unwanted keys.  There was a 'compatibility' key that I had to delete manually.  If I knew regedit better then I probably could wscript it.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent]
@="Mozilla/5.0"
"Platform"="Windows NT 10.1; Win64; x64"
"Version"=" AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
```

I had to do the above to get around browser sniffing at a website.  I use ie11 and the website somehow was able to detect it and force the opening of Microsoft Edge.  I had to use Geek uninstall to get rid of Edge.  The above regedit is a chrome user agent string and that stopped the website from sending me a MSIE 11 version of the site which didn't include JSON that I wanted.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: This didn't work for me because I'm using the official VM's from Microsoft (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) and couldn't get Regedit to open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, `about:flags` failed to do anything. I also couldn't get RegEdit to open on the [Official Microsoft VM for IE11](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

My solution that does work is to use the `f12` developer tools.

- Open up the tools with `f12` or using the gear icon in the top right and choosing **F12 Developer Tools**
- Go to the **Emulation** tab, which looks like an "eject" button for some reason
- In the **Mode** section of the tab, set the pulldown for **User Agent** to what you want.

[image]